# typeViewClicked event is not detected when target window is developed by jetpack compose by my accessibilityservice

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

My accessibilityservice is used to monitor click events generated by the target application.
It works very well in one case.

But recently I received some feedback that some apps are not working. We investigated these target apps and found that they were mostly developed by Jetpack compose.

For Jetpack compose's Button, even after click, it doesn't report TypeViewClicked event to AccessibilityService, is this a developer's problem or Jetpack compose's own defect?